# Call forwarding GOIP16 with asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, gsm

I am trying to dial a call to GOIP and want to forward it to another GSM phone. I have added following lines in my extensions.conf (asterisk)

```
[goip_context]
exten=> 105,1,Set(NUMBER=913579865476)
exten=> 105,2,Dial(SIP/${NUMBER}@${GW2},20)
```

where 105 is my GOIP extension
NUMBER is the dialled number
and GW2=goip

On dialing a call, following logs appear on asterisk terminal

```
Call to peer 'goip' rejected due to usage limit of 1
    -- Couldn't call SIP/913579865476@goip
```

Please guide in this regard

Answer (score 0):

Acordinly to message you have call-limit in sip.conf set to 1 for this section

Also you need at least 2 gsm modules to do that.

Comment: How i can configure 2 gsm modules in order to acheive my usecase